# Relation of $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial q^\kappa}$ with the Curvature of the Configuration Space

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature

$T$ being the kinetic energy and {${q^\kappa}$} being the generalized coordinates, in *Chapter $1$, Page $20$, Classical Mechanics*, Goldstein claims that

> ...speaking in the language of differential geometry, this term, $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial q^\kappa}$, arises from the curvature of the coordinates $q^\kappa$.

But upon a simple calculation, it seems like this can not be the case.

Let's consider a single particle system. Say the metric induced on the configuration space by relations $\vec{x}=\vec{x}(q^1,...,q^n,t)$ is $g_{\mu\nu}$. Here, $\vec{x}$ denotes the position of the particle in the Cartesian physical space. This means that $$|d\vec{x}|^2=g_{\mu\nu}dq^\mu dq^\nu.$$

Therefore,

$$\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial q^\kappa} = \dfrac{m}2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q^k}(g_{\mu\nu} \dot{q}^\mu \dot{q}^\nu) = \dfrac{m}{2}g_{\mu\nu, \kappa}\dot{q}^\mu \dot{q}^\nu.$$

So, clearly, $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial q^\kappa}$ arises out of non-constancy of the metric of the configuration space along the considered generalized coordinate and not out of the curvature of the configuration space (which can certainly be zero even with a non-vanishing $g_{\mu\nu, \kappa}$). So, why does Goldstein claim that $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial q^\kappa}$ arises out of the curvature of the configuration space?

Comment: He mean the curvature of the *coordinates*. The quantity $\partial_\kappa g_{\mu\nu}$ is heavily dependent on coordinates. It's zero for Cartesian coordinates on $\Bbb R^d$, but possibly nonzero for polars.

Comment: How do you define the curvature of coordinates? The standard definition is using the Reimann Tensor afaik. $\partial_\kappa g_{\mu\nu}$ can be non-zero even for completely flat coordinates like, say, cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @Dvij By "curvature of the coordinates" I mean that they're not Cartesian. It's not a precise statement.